# change apk filename when share it from application

Tags: java, android, apk

i share my app with following code :

```
ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
String filePath = app.sourceDir;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share app via"));
```

But the file name that shared is "base.apk",how to change it ?

Comment: Why don't you just share your play store link? Asking for just curiosity.

Comment: because it's a university project and will not be published in store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sharing the app with apk name change, You can copy the apk file to your sd card using the following method, pass ApplicationItem, expected folder and the new expected name for the apk

```
public static File copyFile(ApplicationInfo appInfo, File folderName, String apkName) {

    File initialFile = new File(appInfo.getSourceDir());
    File finalFile = new File(folderName, apkName);

    try {
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(finalFile);
        FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return finalFile;
}
```

Now create an intent using the File which you copied.

```
public static Intent getShareIntent(File file) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    return intent;
}
```

Finally you can share the app,

```
ApplicationInfo app = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();
File newFile = copyFile(app, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "[Expected name].apk");

Intent shareIntent = getShareIntent(newFile);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Sharing [Appname] Apk"));
```

Comment: I can't find ApplicationItem and AppUtil class, why ? In your opinion, where is the problem ?

Comment: sorry I updated the answer, you can directly use the above copy and share method, that is my app class name.

Comment: thanks , but When Invoke copyFile(), it enters the catch block

Comment: do you have permission for external storage..?

Comment: notice i change copyFile Signature to ``** copyFile(ApplicationInfo appInfo, File folderName, String apkName) **``